# Fastest way to restructure a HashMap

Tags: java

I have a HashMap that maps companies to an ArrayList of the products they sell, like so:

```
thiscompany --> [productA, productB...]
thatcompany --> [productC, productA...]
```

Hence it is very easy to generate a list of products given a specific company. Note that multiple companies may sell the same product. The issue is that I also need to, given a specific product, find all the companies that sell it. And quickly. This sort of lookup may happen once, or multiple times. I am wondering the most efficient way to provide this functionality.

Currently I am generating a new data structure by iterating through each ArrayList and mapping each product to its vendor. This is expensive though, because I have to check to see whether the HashMap I am creating contains that product as a key each time before adding, plus it requires me to get the each ArrayList, add the new vendor, delete the old ArrayList then map the new one for each entry. I simply cannot see a faster way of doing this though, perhaps someone can provide me with some insight?

Comment: Why "delete the old arraylist and map the new one?" You fetch the existing one. If it's null, you add one and add the company. Otherwise, you check for the company, and add it if it's not there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about changing the ArrayList to a HashSet.

```
List<String> findCompanies(Map<String,Set<String>> companyToProducts, String product) {
    List<String> companies = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (Map.Entry<String,Set<String>> entry : companyToProducts) {
        Set<String> products = entry.getValue();
        if (products.contains(product)) {
            companies.add(entry.getKey());
        }
    }
    return companies;
}
```

Another common approach would be to use a table in a database with a column for product and a column for company and then do a:

```
select distinct company from companyToProduct where product = 'cheese';
```

Comment: Going to test this now to see how it works. Thanks for the input. Regarding the database alternative, I actually looked at this, but product and company names can change frequently and/or they be removed or added. Currently I am storing the original HashMap in an object database and replacing it whenever the user hits 'update'. Therefore, to save the work of database sync on every update I would 'delete from xtable' and create it anew before doing that query. However I am unsure of the length of time that operation would take, can you provide some insight on this?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you create the map of companies that sell a products at the same time you build the map of products for company

```
Map<Product, Set<Company>> companiesByProduct
Map<Company, Set<Product>> productsByCompany

public void add(Company company, Product product) {
    Set<Company> companies = companiesByProduct.get(product);
    if (companies==null) {
        companies = new HashSet<Company>();
        companiesByProduct.put(product, companies);
    }
    companies.add(company);

    // do the same for 
    Set<Product> products = productsByCompany.get(product);
    ....
```

Or to create new companiesByProduct Map from the map received by the server you could use (you may need to adjust depending on the exactly type of your original map):

```
for (Company company : originalMap.keySet()) {
  for (Product product : originalMap.get(company)) {
    Set<Company> companies = companiesByProduct.get(product);
    if (companies==null) {
        companies = new HashSet<Company>();
        companiesByProduct.put(product, companies);
    }
    companies.add(company);
   }
}
```

Comment: Once you have that you can easily get the companies that seel a product as companiesByProduct.get(product)

Comment: unfortunately I am provided the original HashMap from a server, and I cannot add more data to the transfer, I have to create the alternative structure entirely on the client side.

Comment: can you create the companiesByProduct map once (on the client side, instead of searching through the original map everytime? If you can then you could still use the same code, you would just change it to use the original map from the server to populate the new one.

Comment: Yes, that is what I am trying to do. The problem is I start only with the productsbyCompany map and have to create the companiesByProduct map from it. I am looking for the most efficient way to populate the new map from the old one.

Answer (score 1):

Try [MultiMaps.invertFrom](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release05/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimaps.html#invertFrom%28com.google.common.collect.Multimap,%20M%29),

**Example:**

```
    Multimap<String, Integer> map = HashMultimap.create();
    map.put("a", 3);
    map.put("a", 4);
    map.put("a", 5);
    map.put("b", 5);
    map.put("b", 3);
    map.put("b", 6);
    Multimap<Integer,String> mapInverse=HashMultimap.create();
    Multimaps.invertFrom(map, mapInverse);
    System.out.println(mapInverse);
```

**Output:**

```
{3=[b, a], 4=[a], 5=[b, a], 6=[b]}
```

**Alternative Solution:**

*Here I'm creating a 2D boolean array representing   the company and their products for easy lookup.*

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

import com.google.common.collect.Multimap;
import com.google.common.collect.Sets;
import com.google.common.collect.TreeMultimap;

public class ProductCompanyMap {
    private Multimap<String, String> companyProducts = TreeMultimap.create();
    private boolean[][] ProductCompanyTable;
    private Map<String,Integer> productIndexMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();;
    private Map<String,Integer> companyIndexMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    private String[] productArray;
    private String[] companyArray;;


    {
        companyProducts.put("Britania","Biscuts");
        companyProducts.put("Britania","Soap");
        companyProducts.put("Britania","Cloths");
        companyProducts.put("MicroSoft","Software");
        companyProducts.put("Birla","Cloths");
        companyProducts.put("Birla","Software");
    }
    public ProductCompanyMap(){

        Set<String> companyNames=companyProducts.keySet();
        Set<String> productNames= Sets.newTreeSet(companyProducts.values());
        companyArray = companyNames.toArray(new String[companyNames.size()]);
        createIndexMap(companyIndexMap, companyArray);
        productArray = productNames.toArray(new String[productNames.size()]);
        createIndexMap(productIndexMap,productArray);

        ProductCompanyTable = new boolean[companyArray.length][productArray.length];
        for(int i=0;i<companyArray.length;i++)
            for(int j=0;j<productArray.length;j++){
                if(companyProducts.containsEntry(companyArray[i],productArray[j]))
                    ProductCompanyTable[i][j] = true;
            }

    }

    private void createIndexMap(Map<String,Integer> map,String[] arr){
        for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
            map.put(arr[i], i);
    }

    public List<String> getProductsOfCompany(String companyName){
        List<String> productsOfCompany = new ArrayList<String>();
        Integer companyIndex = null;
        if((companyIndex=companyIndexMap.get(companyName))!=null)
        {
            for(int i=0;i<ProductCompanyTable[companyIndex].length;i++)
                if(ProductCompanyTable[companyIndex][i])
                    productsOfCompany.add(productArray[i]);
        }
        return productsOfCompany;
    }
    public List<String> getCompanysWithProduct(String productName){
        List<String> companysWithProduct = new ArrayList<String>();
        Integer productIndex = null;
        if((productIndex=productIndexMap.get(productName))!=null)
        {
            for(int i=0;i<ProductCompanyTable.length;i++)
                if(ProductCompanyTable[i][productIndex])
                    companysWithProduct.add(companyArray[i]);
        }
        return companysWithProduct;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ProductCompanyMap mm=new ProductCompanyMap();
        System.out.println("Products of Birla : " +mm.getProductsOfCompany("Birla"));
        System.out.println("Company's producing cloths : "+mm.getCompanysWithProduct("Cloths"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maintain two data structures—the HashMap you maintain now and another one that maps products to companies:

```
productA --> [thiscompany, thatcompany...]
productC --> [thatcompany, othercompany...]
```

Comment: yes, this is what I am doing at the moment. The issue is that I have to convert the first data structure into the second one, and I am looking for the most efficient way to do this.