# Java collection for this use case

Tags: java, data-structures, collections, set, hashcode

Let's say we have a bunch of Car objects.

Each Car has some distinguishing properties e.g. manufacturer, model, year, etc. (these can be used to create distinct hashCodes).

Each car has a List of PurchaseOffer objects (a PurchaseOffer object contains pricing\retailer info).

We receive Lists of Cars from several different sources, each Car with a single PurchaseOffer.
Thing is, these lists may overlap - a Car can appear in more than one list.

We wish to aggregate the lists into a single collection of Cars where each Car holds all encountered PurchaseOffers for it.

My Problem is choosing *what to collection to use* in this aggregation process:

Feels natural to use java.util.HashSet for holding our cars, that way when going over the different lists of Cars, we can check if a car already exists in the Set in amortized O(1),
however - you cannot retrieve an element from a Set (in our case - when we go encounter a Car that already exists in the Set - we would have liked to retrieve that Car from the Set based on its identifying hashCode and add PurchaseOffers to it).

I can use a HashMap where each Car's hashCode maps to the actual Car object, but it probably isn't the school-book solution since it is unsafe - I would have to make sure myself that every hashCode maps to a Car with that hashCode - there could be inconsistency.
Of course, can make a designated data structure that guarantees this consistency - Shouldn't one already exist ?

Can anyone suggest the data-structure I am after, or point out a design mistake ?
Thanks.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by unsafe?

Comment: If we decide that we use a Map that maps a hashCode to a Car object with that hashCode, nothing prevents us from inserting into this map an incorrect key-value e.g some arbitrary key X that maps to a Car with a hashCode that is different from X. If this data structure was to be used by other programmers i.e. client users of the code, that would be unacceptable.

Comment: check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5334887/fastest-way-to-restructure-a-hashmap/5335015#5335015) for similar problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that you really do need (at least) a `HashMap<Car, List<PurchaseOffer>>` ... as suggested by @Andreas_D

Your objection that each `Car` already has a `List<PurchaseOffer>` is beside the point.  The list in the `HashMap` is the aggregate list, containing *all* `PurchaseOffer` objects from all `Car` objects that stand for the same physical car.

The point of creating a new list is to avoid changing the original lists on the original `Car` objects.  (If that was not a concern, then you could pick one instance of `Car` from the set that represent a physical car, and merge the `PurchaseOffer` objects from the others into that list.)

I'm not entirely sure why @duffymo suggested a bi-directional map between, but I think it is because the different `Car` objects from different sources may have complementary (or contradictory) information for the same physical car.  By keeping all instances, you avoid discarding information.  (Once again, if you are happy to discard mutate and/or discard information, you could attempt to merge the information about each individual car into a single `Car` object.

---

If you really didn't care about preserving information and were prepared to merge stuff willy-nilly then the following approach would probably work:

```
  HashMap<Car, Car> map = new HashMap<Car, Car>(...);
  for (Car car : carsToBeAggregated) {
      Car master = nap.get(car);
      if (master == null) {
          map.put(car, car);
      } else {
          master.offers.addAll(car.offers);
          // optionally, merge other Car information from car to master
      }
  }
```

---

You should NOT be trying to use the `Car.hashCode()` as a key for anything.  Hashcode values are not unique identifiers: there is a distinct possibility that two different cars will end up with the same hashcode value.  If you attempt to use them as if they were unique identifiers you'll get into trouble ...

Comment: +1 for the second part of the answer.  A Car -> Car map is the minimal data structure that provides everything the OP asked for.  (Although maybe they wanted things that they didn't ask for.)

Comment: There is no other information, it simply isn't a many-to-many scenario. Great answer, second part of your answer is a very nice solution!

Answer (score 6):

Since this is a many-to-many relationship, you need a bi-directional multi-map.  Car is the key for the first one, with a List of PurchaseOrder as the value.  The PurchaseOrder is the key for the second one, with a List of Cars as the value.

The underlying implementation is two HashMaps.

Put an API on top of it to get the behavior you need.  Or see if [Google Collections](http://code.google.com/p/google-collections/) can help you.  It's a combination of a BiMap and two MultiMaps.

Comment: I get why a multi-map would come handy, but why the bi-directionality?  My problem with a multi-map is that the List<PurchaseOffer> is **a property** of the Car object, i.e. it is not something that is external to the Car object, but is contained within it.

Comment: Maybe it should be externalized.  Making it a data member of Car or a separate class altogether are just two design choices among many.  You may know your problem better than I do.  Or maybe not.  You said earlier that a Car had a PurchaseOrder, and in your comment it's a List of PurchaseOrders.  Which is it?

Answer (score 3):

The basic datastructure should be a `HashMap<Car, List<PurchaseOffer>>`. This allows for storing and receiving all offers for one selected car.

Now you may have to find a suitable implementation for `Car.equals()` to assure, that "cars" coming from different source are really the same. What about basing `equals()` on a unique identifier for a real world car (VIN)?

Comment: Welp, yeah, HashMap<Car, List<PurchaseOffer>> would be perfect if it wasn't for the fact that each Car **contains** a List<PurchaseOffer> as a property. Can say that a Car object is composed of two parts: an identifying part (let's say each car indeed has a unique VIN), and the list of PurchaseOffers.

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer to use a `HashMap<Car, List<PurchaseOffer>>`, as suggested before (Andreas, Stephen), mainly if the Car object does **not** hold the list of PurchaseOffers.
Otherwise I would consider using a `HashMap<Car, Car>` or, better IMO, a `HashMap<ID, Car>` if there is an unique ID for each Car.

It can **not** simply map the Car's hashCode to the Car, as mentioned in the question, since distinct Cars can have the same hashCode!

(Anyway, I would create an own class for storing and managing the Cars. This would contain the HashMap, or whichever - so it's easy to change the implementation without needing to change its interface)

Comment: I was wondering if a data structure such as the one you mention in the last paragraph of your answer already exists. Guess it doesn't.

Comment: @bloodcell - I don't know any, despite I think the HashSet is implemented (more or less) that way; but it is missing a method to retrieve the actually saved instance.

Answer (score 0):

create tout custom class that extends hash
Set,
 override method contains(Object o)
 check there os hash code is same or not and return result according, and add object to set of and only if it not containing that object

Answer (score 0):

How about a defining a new custom Aggregation class? Define the hashcode such that the id of the car acts as the key and override the equals() accordingly. Define a custom method for accepting your original car and do a union operation on the lists. Finally store the custom objects in a HashSet for achieving constant time look up.

In purist terms, aggregation is a behavior beyond the scope of a single object. Visitor pattern tries to address a similar problem.

Alternatively if you have a sql datastore, a simple select using group by would do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

```
    //alt. 1
    List<Offer> offers;
    List<Car> cars;
    Map<Car, List<Offer>> mapCarToOffers;
    Map<Offer, List<Car>> mapOfferToCars;
    public void List<Offer> getOffersForCar(Car aCar);
    public void List<Car> getCarsForOffer(Offer anOffer);
```

**Alternative 1** would make use of the `hashCode()` of `Car` and `Offer`

```
    //alt. 2
    List<Offer> offers;
    List<Car> cars;
    Map<Integer, List<Offer>> mapCarIdToOffers;
    Map<Integer, List<Car>> mapOfferIdToCars;
    public void List<Offer> getOffersForCarId(int aCarId);
    public void List<Car> getCarsForOfferId(int anOfferId);
```

**Alternative 2** would make use of the `hashCode()` of `Integer`. This would allay your concerns about "safety" as the hash codes for `Integer` objects should not overlap where the values are unique. This incurs the additional overhead of having to maintain unique IDs for each `Car` and `Offer` object, however, I am guessing that you probably already have those from your business requirements.
Note, you may choose to use other classes as alternative to `int`s for ID's (e.g. `String`).

For both alternatives, implement the `List`s with `ArrayList` or `LinkedList` - which one is better is up to you to determine based on other requirements, such as the frequency of insertion/deletion vs lookup. Implement the `Map`s with `HashMap` - see comments above about how hash codes are used.

---

As a side note, in our software, we use these both of the above to represent similar types of many-to-many data. Very similar to your use case.
Both alternatives work very well.

Answer (score 0):

> Welp, yeah, `HashMap<Car, List<PurchaseOffer>>` would be perfect if it wasn't for the fact that
>   each `Car` contains a `List<PurchaseOffer>` as a property. Can say that a `Car` object is composed
>   of two parts: an identifying part (let's say each car indeed has a unique VIN), and the list of
>   `PurchaseOffer`s.

In this case split the Car class in two classes - the CarType class with the identifying attributes, and then the list part (maybe both together used by `Car`). Then use `Map<CarType, Lost<PurchaseOffer>` for your datastructure (or `MultiMap<CarType, PurchaseOffer>`).

Answer (score -1):

Why not use an object database for this? You could store any object graph you wanted, and you'd get a search API with which you could do any relationship/retrieval mechanism you wanted. A simple collection could work, but it sounds like you want a more complex relationship than a collection would provide. Look into db4o (http://db4o.com) - it's very powerful for this sort of thing.

Comment: Java lets you define any object graph you want, too.  Adding a database to the mix--without needing features like atomicity of transactions and serialization--is a perfectly delightful way to make the problem much harder.

Comment: In all fairness, adding a database like db4o - an object database - doesn't make ACID a requirement in order to interact with the database. And db4o allows you to search that object graph easily and conveniently. It's not a requirement, of course - java serialization works. But again: it doesn't sound like a simple graph is what he is looking for.

Comment: The OP doesn't need serialization.  He just needs a hash map.  It's built in and trivial to use.  db4o is not built in, and is not as trivial to use.  It's a great solution for _some_ problems, but not this one!  (Unless the OP needs a lot more than they're asking for.)

Comment: Sure, that's fair enough. Yet I figured if a simple object collection was all he needed, it'd be fairly obvious to him, so he probably needed more. And I'd say db4o *is* pretty trivial to use - esp for in-memory graphs, and adding dependencies to java application is pretty normal behavior. (Although note that I do a lot of EE stuff, so maybe it's more normal in that arena than others.)